# How to filter Date Month And Year in php from a timestamp field from database

Tags: php, mysql, database

i have a cms in php where i make booking records in my db i want to make a report about a bookings for a specific month/year in order for that i need to filter those record according to my need when i put a month all the records are displayed in my table of that month this can also be applied for the year record...

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        console.log("hello");
        var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
        input = document.getElementById("myinput");
        filter = input.options[input.selectedIndex].text;
        date = new Date(filter);
        month = date.getMonth().toString();
        filter = month;
        //console.log(filter);
        table = document.getElementById("mytable");
        tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
        for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
            td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[6];
            if (td) {
                // txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
                txtValue = new Date(td.innerText).getMonth().toString();
                console.log(txtValue);
                if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                    tr[i].style.display = "";
                } else {
                    tr[i].style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
Filter Date:
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Month</label>
    <select name="date" id="myinput">
        <?php
        $query = "SELECT * FROM package_booking WHERE date";
        $select_date = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
        confirmQuery($select_date);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_date)) {
            $pb_id = $row['pb_id'];
            $date = $row['date'];
            $mon = date('m', strtotime($date));
            echo "<option value=''>{$date}</option>";
        }
        ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

this code i made is in JS but now i need to know the php part that can filter records in my DB in order to get a record for a month.

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't formatted properly, but You might want to try something like:

```
SELECT * FROM `your_db_name` WHERE Year(the_date_field_in_your_db) = 'the_year_you_need' AND MONTH(the_date_field_in_your_db)= 'date_numerical_value';
```

Dates are usually stored in number (1 for January, 2 for February, etc).